# cant run php files in a folder on windows 7 webserver which was previously created on xp webserver?

Tags: php, permissions, copy, webserver, directory

im doing a php project. all is fine doing it in xp webserver which im using iis..but now i have set up a new pc with windows 7 and iis.

problem is when i copy my php files which is in a folder(e.g portal1) from the xp wwwroot to the windows 7 wwwroot, i cant access it on the browser. it returns an internal server error.

now i assumed i didnt properly set up my web server or even php. i have done it a dozen times following tutorials and im pretty sure its all correct.

i have done a further research on the folder itself and has led me to a theory that this has to do with permissions.

when i copy directly the whole thing,it wont run, BUT if i CREATE a folder and the subfolder with all the same names as the one i copied and just take the php files and put it accordingly, it runs ok!!

now that has something to do with inherited permission i think. how do i overcome this?
i dont want to everytime take the updated work folder from my partner which is done in xp and i have to create new folder and its subfolder with all the same name on my machine and then copy the php files accordingly. thats a lot of work!!

i just want to copy the folder and put it in my wwwroot folder and run it on the browser without problems. how do i overcome this permission issue?

any ideas?

Comment: make sure that there in't an old .htaccess inside(with maybe wrong settings for the new environment)

Comment: 500 errors get logged in the server's error log. I'd start with looking there to see what the real reason is, rather than flailing around in the dark.

Comment: nope @Dr.Molle . i have make sure there's no htaccess.

Comment: sorry for this silly question @Marc B but where do i navigate to get that log.im using iis7.

Comment: It'd probably be in the same place as the access logs. Check in the config manager for IIS to find the exact location.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of things, you're working on a project with someone else. Copying & pasting is  the absolute worst way of sharing files when working on a project with multiple people. You should really be using versioning like git. That's pretty hard to set up and learn though. An easy solution which will work for the time being (but won't manage conflicts well) is to use Dropbox. Set up a free Dropbox account, and create a folder in that called www or whatever you want. Then install WAMP (way better than IIS), and create an alias to the www folder in your Dropbox. Do this on both machines. Now every time your partner makes a change, it will be instantly reflected on your machine, and vice versa. Easy, free, and will work while you learn a versioning tool.

I know this doesn't address your actual problem, but it should be more helpful to you.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i did consider dropbox but turns out i dont want our work to be synchornized in case if there's unintentional deletion or anything.so i thought better for me to have all the previous versions so that i can keep track.

Comment: the reason why im not using wamp is because im using oracle as my database..using wamp or xampp makes it hard for me to configure. plus for some reason apache wont start when my oracle database is installed. so thats why im using iis at the moment..however i do prefer apache.

Comment: Dropbox backs up your files, and you should be backing up your files as well. But that's all annoying stuff, versioning will solve that issue completely and you'll never even have to think about it.

Comment: can u explain to me about versioning @Christian Varga . sounds interesting. any examples of the tool?